# I have a problem with Mathplotlib in python about the order of Y axis is wrong

Tags: python, graph

I wanna create a sample graph. But something was wrong in the sorting order of the Y-Axis.

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAOsi.jpg)

I wonder why I defined X-axis as `plt.xlim(0, 200)`. when I tried to show the plot, the order was correct, but in the same way, I also defined the y-axis, the result was wrong. Which part I missed or I was incorrect?

Here my code:

***suppose that y is a list of many values (length = 110)***

```
y = ['80', '35', '28', '25', '24', '25', '26', '27', '27', '26', '25', '27', '31', '25', '25', '25', '26', '29', '28', '27', '27', '26', '32', '27', '24', '25', '24', '31', '26', '28', '28', '26', '32', '27', '27', '25', '25', '26', '28', '26', '25', '25', '25', '27', '27', '27', '24', '23', '30', '28', '25', '23', '24', '26', '28', '25', '25', '26', '26', '25', '25', '24', '24', '24', '27', '28', '27', '25', '25', '26', '26', '26', '25', '24', '22', '31', '29', '26', '27', '26', '28', '26', '29', '24', '30', '31', '27', '28', '25', '31', '30', '28', '26', '24', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27'...]

x2 = range(0,110)

fig = plt.subplot()
plt.title('Test')
plt.plot(x2, y, 'o-')
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.xlim(0,200)
plt.ylabel('A')
plt.show()
```

Anyone could explain the reason why Y-axis was wrong, despite I defined `plt.ylim()` already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is your `y` is strings, and strings do not get ordered when processed into the plot.

You don't need to use `xlim` or `ylim` unless you want the graph to show a padded or cropped version of your data. Otherwise, the most fitting size is chosen automatically.

You can use a list comprehension as shown, or `map(int, y)` to get a list of ints.

```
y_int = [int(y_i) for y_i in y]
x2 = range(0,len(y))

fig = plt.subplot()
plt.title('Test')
plt.plot(x2, y_int, 'o')
plt.ylabel('A')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much I will be careful with data type